# client side signalr is slowing down application in browser

Tags: javascript, signalr

Need your guide, please.
as shown in the diagram I have integrated Azure Signalr chat in my application through client-side scripts. it is causing slowness and crashing in the browser due to insufficient resources.
this only happens when signalr script is enabled and signalr connection is in use.
otherwise, the application is working fine.
We also have a separate chat application that works perfectly fine with a large number of users.

The issue is happening in the client application only when we are testing with 80 to 100 users. in reality there are thousands of users who will use signlar chat. I am worried about how this signalr will work.

Note: I have managed to limit single signalr connection for each user even in multiple tabs. but onclose event is called after few intervals so I have to call start function which is a normal thing. but cause of onclose event is not known. There is not internet glitch.
can somebody help me how to figure out the cause of onclose function and how I can manage to make signalr work without slowing the client application

There is only a slowness issue. no 400 or 500 error.

Thanks[image]

Comment: There is only slowness issue. no 400 or 500 error.

Comment: As always, look at your browser dev tools' performance/profiler tools to figure out where time is being spent.

Comment: I observed network section. file loading goes timeout but only in the case when this signalr is in use.
one thing I for got to mention. in application there is another signalr, an old version also working for some other purpose

Comment: Looking at the Network tab won't help with figuring out with "slowness and crashing". Use the performance/profiler tabs.